# Read FileStream with timeout

Tags: c#, timeout, filestream

I wrote this code to read some data from a FileStream with a timeout:

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource RCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();

private int ReadTimeOut = 500;

//...

private byte[] ReadData()   //Blocking Method (until operation done or timeout)
{
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[ReadSize];
    Task<int> ReadTask = FStream.ReadAsync(Buffer, 0, ReadSize, RCTS.Token);    //Problem
    if (ReadTask.Wait(ReadTimeOut))
    {
        if (ReadTask.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled) RCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();   //Cancelled manually
        return Buffer;
    }
    RCTS.Cancel();
    RCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
    throw new TimeoutException("Read operation timed out.");
}
```

However, code stops on `//Problem` line until read operation is done (enough data available). So timeout is useless.
`FStream.CanTimeout` is false and I can't use `FStream.ReadTimeout`. `FStream` is async.

Why it stops there? Shouldn't it just assign `ReadTask` and then run it on `ReadTask.Wait(ReadTimeOut)`?

Comment: Shouldn't you do `new CancellationTokenSource(500);`?

Comment: A file is a string and you have Task<int>

Comment: @jdweng ReadAsync returns an int to indicate how many bytes are read into the buffer

Comment: @rene If I do that way I can't understand if it was a manual cancellation or a timeout.

Comment: Won't the RCTS have IsCancellationRequested == true ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.iscancellationrequested?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: But if I want to cancel it manually, I use `RCTS.Cancle();`. Doesn't it also set `IsCancellationRequested` to true?

Comment: have two tokens and link them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @rene Thanks. I'll use this solution. But I'm still curious why my code stops on that `//Problem` line?

Comment: It stops because it has nowhere to go. There isn't an await on that line so no magic happens.

Comment: @rene New problem: How should I understand if read operation completed before timeout? I also tried `IAsyncResult result = FStream.ReadAsync(...);` but same problem happens.